# Combining DispatchGroup and DispatchQueue

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, dispatchgroup

My scenario is like this. I need to send a Network Request, in response i will become a list of Image URLs. I would then need to send multiple network requests concurrently to get all of these Images and once i have all the Images downloaded , I need to populate a `tableView`.

To fulfil these requirements i am trying to understand the relationship between `DispatchQueue` and `DispatchGroup` in Playground and so far this is my code.

```
var concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "test",attributes: .concurrent)
var myGroup = DispatchGroup()
var mySecondGroup = DispatchGroup()

myGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
    print("Initial Json request with List of URLs completed")
    mySecondGroup.enter()
    concurrentQueue.async {
        for i in 10...15 {
            print(i)
            if(i==15){
                mySecondGroup.leave()
            }
        }
    }
}

mySecondGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
    print("All Images download complete")
}

myGroup.enter()
concurrentQueue.async {
    for i in 0...5 {
        print(i)
        if(i==5){
            myGroup.leave()
        }
    }
    
}
```

The problem is i am getting the result

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
Initial Json request with List of URLs completed
10
11
All Images download complete
12
13
14
15
```

But what i want is something like this

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
Initial Json request with List of URLs completed
10
11
12
13
14
15
All Images download complete
```

I am not really understanding what i am doing wrong here and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/U7k32tKs should work.

Comment: how does it work ?

Comment: You need to match an "enter" with each "leave", that's how the group knows when the set of tasks has completed.

Comment: But i think i have done that. We start myGroup.enter() and then myGroup.leave() which in turn triggers the notify method of myGroup where i do mySecondGroup.enter() and then after process mySecondGroup.leave(). So i think i have matched each "enter" with "leave"

Comment: But, you called `mySecondGroup.enter()` too late, it should have called already its `notify()`. Also, put notify in the end (at least after a `enter()` by custom), else it might also be called too soon.

Comment: I don't understand. Why would mySecondGroup call its notify method at all before mysecondGroup.leave is called.

Comment: That's not what is happening. You have more leaves than enters, so the second notify occurs before you want it to.

Comment: How ? As far as i understand i have myGroup.enter() and then inside the if condition myGroup.leave() that should trigger the myGroup.notify(). Inside this method i have another mySecondGroup.enter() and then in inside the if condition i have another mySecondGroup.leave(). 1 Enter and 1 Leave respectively on each group. Maybe i am understanding it all wrong ?

Comment: Are your prints consistent?

Comment: `DispatchGroup` is pointless for a single asynchronous task because you can proceed  directly in the completion handler.

Comment: @Don Yes, I am getting the same results everytime

Comment: @vadian But i have 2 asynschronous task. First is to download the json and get all the image urls and second is to download all the images concurrently.

Comment: With *a single asynchronous task* I mean one call without a loop.

Comment: The reason I asked if your prints are consistent is because you can't rely on their output from different queues like that. Wrap _all_  your prints in a `DispatchQueue.main.async` block and you'll get your expected output every time.

Answer (score 3):

`DispatchQueue` is the medium where the tasks are scheduled on.

`DispatchGroup` works like a counter. Calling `enter` increments the counter (usually before calling the asynchronous task) and `leave` decrements the counter (usually inside the completion handler). When the counter reaches zero the group notifies.

Your scenario needs something like this

```
let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "test",attributes: .concurrent)
let group = DispatchGroup()
concurrentQueue.async {
    asynchronousAPI.call() { urls in
        for url in urls {
            group.enter()
            asynchronousImageLoad(url) { data in
               // process data
               group.leave()
            }
        }
    }
}
group.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("done")
}
```